# Tokenize a string based on punctuation

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm having some issues trying to split a string by punctuation. Specifically every character that belongs to string.punctuation. For example for the string

Input:

```
"Hi. How2 are you doing??    "
```

I would like the output:

```
['Hi', '.', 'How2', 'are', 'you', 'doing', '?', '?')
```

For reference string.punctuation is:

```
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

I would like any character in the string to be its own token.

I've currently tried using `re.split()`. However, all I've been able to achieve is splitting based on non word characters. For example:

```
print([i for i in re.split(r'(\W+)', 'hi. how are you   doing') if i])
```

which gives the output:

```
['hi', '. ', 'how', ' ', 'are', ' ', 'you', '   ', 'doing', '??']
```

Furthermore, the two `'??'` should be split. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a minor comment, you don't need to say [i for i in re.split(...) if i] ... the "if i" is entirely redundant, and if you really can't just say print(re.split(...)) <I don't know, I am not familiar with Python 3's print() or the re module's split()> you can just say print(list(re.split()))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> import re
>>> mystr = "Hi. How2 are you doing??    "
>>> re.findall(r'[.?]|\w+', mystr)
['Hi', '.', 'How2', 'are', 'you', 'doing', '?', '?']
>>>
```

The pattern above finds all occurrences of `.`, `?`, or a series of one or more word characters.  I kept the pattern simple just to demonstrate, but any other punctuation characters that you want to capture would be placed inside the character set `[...]`.

Also, you may want to use [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) instead of typing out all of those punctuation characters.

Answer (score 1):

A little late on this.

You should be able to do this with split().

All you're doing is consuming whitespace, so everything else is between characters.

Example:  `\s+|\b|(?=\pP)` will split on (and consume) whitespace, or word boundry,
or punctuation (within a look ahead).

Don't have Python to test with, but in Perl

```
   $data =~ s/^\s+//;      # <- trim leading spaces (a Perl problem)
   my @vals = split /\s+|\b|(?=\pP)/, $data;
```

gives `['Hi', '.', 'How2', 'are', 'you', 'doing', '?', '?']`

For reference, this raw regex is the same thing

```
\s+|\b|(?=[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~])
```

but is with the punctuation characters in your list.

*Note that the inverse is to find all words and punctuation*.  For every split there
is a negative find all ...

Answer (score 0):

for this [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) exist:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> a = "Hi. How2 are you doing??    "
>>> nltk.sent_tokenize(a)
['Hi.', 'How2 are you doing?', '?    ']
>>> nltk.word_tokenize(a)
['Hi.', 'How2', 'are', 'you', 'doing', '?', '?']
>>> map(nltk.word_tokenize,nltk.sent_tokenize(a))
[['Hi', '.'], ['How2', 'are', 'you', 'doing', '?'], ['?']]
```

I have use a little feature, nltk is vast and powerfull , take a look at it

Comment: Note however that NLTK is a 3rd-party library.  It is not available on the standard build of Python.

Comment: yes it is 3rd party library, but its exist for a purpose

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention in the questions that I would like to not use NLTK

Comment: @user3750474 its ok then check iCodez ans